# Dropdown menu for multiple-choice questions with exams2moodle

Tags: dropdown, moodle, r-exams

I use Sweave (Rnw) questions using `exams2moodle()` from R/exams. All works fine except when I'm trying to use dropdown question for schoice or mchoice questions. Following the manual I try to use the option `cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTICHOICE"`, but that does not work.

I include an example Rnw exercise along with my R code below.

```
\begin{question}
Which is a parameter?
\begin{answerlist}
\item population mean.
\item sample mean.
\item sample variance.
\item sample mode.
\item sample standard deviation.
\item population mode
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

%% \expoints{5}
%% \extype{mchoice}
%% \exsolution{100001}
%% \exshuffle{5}
```

Replication code:

```
library("exams")
exams2moodle("cloze_dropdown.Rnw", n=3, name = "dropdown")
make_question_moodle(cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTICHOICE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. If you want to set the `cloze_mchoice_display` option you need to do so via

   ```
   exams2moodle(..., cloze = list(cloze_mchoice_display = "..."))
   ```

   Internally, this calls the `make_question_moodle()` code. You don't have to do that yourself.
2. As the name conveys, the `cloze_mchoice_display` is only used for mchoice elements within cloze exercises (and not standalone mchoice questions). So in the meta-information you need to set the `extype` tag to `cloze` (rather than `mchoice`) and additionally set the `exclozetype` tag to `mchoice`. In Rnw exercises:

   ```
   \extype{cloze}
   \exclozetype{mchoice}
   ```
3. The dropdown menu just lets you select a single answer so this is really intended for schoice elments (where it's actually the default inside cloze questions). So you can only use `MULTIRESPONSE` displays for mchoice elements and `MULTICHOICE` displays only for schoice elements.

Thus, you need to decide whether you want:

- An mchoice question. Then I would keep it as it is in your question but then you cannot have a dropdown menu.
- A dropdown menu. Then you need to turn it into an schoice question with only a single correct answer. If put into a cloze the dropdown menu is the default display in `exams2moodle(...)`.

As an example, when you use the Rnw exercise below you will get a dropdown menu in Moodle by default.

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
stat <- sample(c("mean", "mode"), 1)
@

\begin{question}
Which is a parameter?
\begin{answerlist}
\item population \Sexpr{stat}.
\item sample mean.
\item sample variance.
\item sample mode.
\item sample standard deviation.
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

%% \expoints{5}
%% \extype{cloze}
%% \exclozetype{schoice}
%% \exsolution{10000}
%% \exshuffle{5}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After adding the code in No 1 in the .R file and No 2 in the .Rnw file I am getting the following error message:  Error in split.default(solutionlist, gr) : 
  first argument must be a vector

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you need at least R/exams 2.4-0 (currently the development version on R-Forge) for this: `install.packages("exams", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654616/how-do-i-create-a-cloze-question-type-with-a-combination-of-single-and-multiple/64675593#64675593

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more concrete comments for your setup. Hopefully, this gets your example working now.

Comment: Awesome!.You are great. It works. Thank you so much for your time and the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. That way your question is flagged as answered here on StackOverflow.