# Logical solutions, FALSE, TRUE export wrongly to moodle

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I've solutions of a cloze question, sol4=FALSE and sol5=TRUE but when I export the exercise to moodle with exsolution: `r mchoice2moodle(sol4)`|`r mchoice2moodle(sol5)`,  both solutions equal TRUE (corresponding to c and d)! Do you know this is some kind of Moodle bug or what am I doing wrong?
[image: r code]

[image: moodle exported question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot represent logical questions/answers by multiple-choice questions of length 1 in Moodle. In R/exams, `mchoice` questions are allowed to have this format and hence no error is generated. But in Moodle, the corresponding `MULTIRESPONSE` type needs to have at least two choice and at least one of these needs to be true.

Therefore, instead of using a multiple-choice question of length 1, I would use a single-choice question of length 2 like this:

```
Question
========
The p-value is: ##ANSWER1##

The null hypothesis is: ##ANSWER2##

Answerlist
----------
* 
* not rejected
* rejected

Meta-information
================
exname: Hypothesis test
extype: cloze
exclozetype: num|schoice
exsolution: 0.123|10
```

Then you get a simple drop-down menu with both choices rather than just a single check box. This also has the advantage that you can clearly distinguish between not answering and not true.

[image: Moodle cloze screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. Drop-down questions are the ones that I use the most. However, they present a problem when exporting to moodle as it makes math expressions appear twice in the possible answers.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem with the rendering in Moodle which we cannot fix from the R/exams side. However, you can also use a display with radio buttons instead of drop-down menus by setting `exams2moodle(..., cloze = list(cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_V"))` or alternatively `MULTICHOICE_H` (vertical vs. horizontal).

Comment: For further discussion, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250064/dropdown-menu-for-multiple-choice-questions-with-exams2moodle As well as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654616/how-do-i-create-a-cloze-question-type-with-a-combination-of-single-and-multiple

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Did it work? If so, it would be great if you could accept the answer (by clicking the check mark on the left of it) or provide further details so that we can resolve the problem.